# Active Directory Autologin without Popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

Is there a way to auto-log a user in who is logged into active-directory without propmting them to use the login dialog.

I cannot set the Auth method to windows as there are 5 differant login methods.

Thanks

Comment: as you have 5 login methods, how do you know you should log in some user without prompting? Domain authenticated users should never get a login dialog?

Comment: Pretty much, if they are on AD then log them in, if not ship them to the login page.

Comment: http://beensoft.blogspot.com/2008/06/mixing-forms-and-windows-authentication.html

Comment: Pino, the problem with the scenario you're describing (bypassing the login page), is that you're assuming the user at the keyboard is the user that is logged onto the machine. That's a fairly risky assumption. In my mind, if an application requires a login, it should *always* require a login. I don't want a legitimate user to walk away from the keyboard, and have the janitor walk up to the machine, fire the application up, and start using it.

Comment: If the user left his machine unlocked then he acted against common rules... at least in germany this is part of the "common-working-evironment-agreement"...

Comment: @David: That's all good and well, and I agree. However, as a software developer, my job is to guard sensitive data from users who are not authorized to access it. I can't prevent users from leaving their machines unlocked when they walk away from it. I *can*, however, insist that they log into a secure application, and *prove* who they are. When it comes to security, paranoia is the path to enlightment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could automatic login only get to work with IE and cookies..

this is a snippet from the web.config that might help:

```
<!-- roles -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AuthCookieRoleManager">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AuthCookieRoleManager" type="CustomWeb.CustomAuthCookieRoleManager"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name="ADAuth" timeout="10" path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true"/>

<!-- roles -->
<location path="Allocation">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="CustomRoleX"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

If this does not meet your requirements, i guess you have to customize the provider..